# Как определить включен или выключен принтер в данный момент?

Tags: c++builder, windows, c++

Здравствуйте. В С++ Builder пишу функцию (потом добавлю в основной модуль программы) определения состояния принтера (включен/выключен). Пока работает некорректно. Подскажите в каком направлении копать. Может есть готовые решения? Спасибо.

Comment: а как определяем, что принтер "включен\выключен". Не нужно забывать, что принтеры есть сетевые, а есть локальные и их нужно проверять немного по разному.

Comment: Речь пока о локальном принтере.
Собираюсь вытащить признак Включен/Выключен через SetPrinter -> PRINTER___INFO_2
Сработает отпишу. Если не туда копаю просигнальте.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы определить состояние принтера можно воспользоваться возможностями WMI: [Win32_Printer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(VS.85).aspx). [Пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=VS.85).aspx) работы с WMI из C++. Другая возможность: [Print Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686807%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, через что подключен принтер??USB? LPT? ComPort?Если ЮЗБ, то придеться трудиться)) С ЛПТ и ком портами работать легче,и компоненты много для них.Если ЮЗБ то возможно запросить статуса с помощью PJL(Printer Job Language).HP принтерам есть исходник на офиц. сайте, как раз для всех принтеров HP на С++(как ни странно,да?)
Во многих случаях предлогають работать с функциями
WriteFile,CreateFile,Readfile.Удачи!